# Can you use the green Mosque tile more than once per turn?

Tags: istanbul

I have a question about the green Mosque tile:

[image: Green tile]

The [rules](http://www.pegasus.de/fileadmin/_downloads/regeln/englisch/Istanbul_-_Anleitung_gb.pdf) say:

> When using one of the three Warehouses `2` `3` `4`, you may pay 2 Lira to gain **1** additional good of any type.

On your turn, **may you use this ability more than once?**

The rules for the yellow tile include "Once on your turn", and the rules for the red tile say "(1x)", so one would guess that the rules for the green tile would include a restriction like that *if* it would be limited. However, the "1" (in "1 additional good") is printed in bold, while the "2" (in "2 Lira") is not. Is this a hint that you can only ever get one good per turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [thread on boardgamegeek.com about the same question](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1188290/green-mosque-tile-limited-once-turn):

**You can use this ability only once per turn.**

Grzegorz Kobiela (who is credited as English translator of *Istanbul’s* rules) and André Bronswijk (who [works for](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/16054823#16054823) *Istanbul’s* publisher *Pegasus Spiele*) [both](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/16059170#16059170) [confirmed](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/18125380#18125380) this.

The reasoning is: You can use this ability **when *using*** a Warehouse, and you only use a Warehouse once per turn.

It’s probably an oversight that a clarifying "1x" is missing in the rules for the green tile (or that it was added to the rules for the red tile, which follows the same logic).

(For reference, [another thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1319526/two-questions-about-mosque-tiles) about it.)